# Android emulator display is not working in linux

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, android-intent, android-emulator

I m a new user to ubuntu(linux). The android emulator is working in it. But the display in it is not working . Could anyone get me a solution for this bug . I tried a lot of things ,but it did not work out. Its definitely working as the logcat shows this log when i click the home button.

03-05 18:40:49.729: I/ActivityManager(62): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher } from pid 62

And i did imaginably locked the screen and tried to unlock the  screen . Which too worked out 
and the logcat log for that activity is

03-05 18:40:46.089: I/ActivityManager(62): Displayed com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher: +4m33s183ms

Get me a solution please . 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/). It is way faster (and better) than the Eclipse's or Android Studios's emulator.